# Mi AJAX function no envia el data al POST

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Al parecer mi AJAX recibe el valor seleccionado, pero al enviarlo al documento php no lo reconoce, por más que intento no veo el fallo.

codigo HTML:

```
<select name="language" id="language" class="select">

  <option selected value="bash">bash</option>
  <option value="cmd">Windows CMD</option>

</select>
```

codigo JS:

```
$('#language').val(function() {
        let lenguage = $(this).val(); //Recongue el valor i lo guarda en la variable
        console.log("="+lenguage); //Efectivamente lo guarda i lo veo en la consola

        $.ajax({
            url: 'assets/php/prove.php',
            method: "POST",
            data: { lenguage },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("-"+lenguage); //Hace el success correctamente
            }
        })
    });
```

codigo PHP:

```
$language = $_POST["lenguage"]; //No recogue la variable enviada en el javascript
echo ">>" . $language . "<<"; //Al no haver nada, no printa la variable solo el ">><<"

if ($language == "bash") {
  echo '<script>console.log("Entro");</script>';
    $dir = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\lscommands\commands\bash\allcommands.txt';
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuando se debe de ejecutar la llamada AJAX, cuando selecciones algún dato del select?

Comment: Desde un principio ya cogue el dato y lo guarda perfectamente a la variable de js "lenguage", el problema esta en que el php no recibe el dato.

Aun poniendo:
    ...data: "bash",...
En el ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que lenguaje es la variable donde tienes tu valor, pero no le haz especificado como lo vas a tomar por POST, así debería funcionar.

```js
$('#language').val(function() {
        let lenguage = $(this).val(); //Recongue el valor i lo guarda en la variable
        console.log("="+lenguage); //Efectivamente lo guarda i lo veo en la consola

        $.ajax({
            url: 'assets/php/prove.php',
            method: "POST",
            data: { lenguaje: lenguage },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("-"+lenguage); //Hace el success correctamente
            }
        })
    });
```

Comment: No aun asi no funciona. El lenguaje: que es lo que hace??

Comment: Es la forma de mandar el dato al servidor, puedes verificarlo en la parte de hasta bajo [aquí](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

Cambia la opción de method:"POST" por type:"POST"

ejemplo:

```
$('#language').val(function() {
        let lenguage = $(this).val(); //Recongue el valor i lo guarda en la variable
        console.log("="+lenguage); //Efectivamente lo guarda i lo veo en la consola

        $.ajax({
            url: 'assets/php/prove.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: { lenguage:lenguage },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("-"+lenguage); //Hace el success correctamente
            }
        })
    });
```

Comment: Ya lo intente, de hecho en un principio tenia el type pero luego lo cambie a method. Es como si algo esta mal en la conexion del javascript y el php, aun que en este mismo archivo js tengo otro ajax que funciona a la perfección.

Answer (score 0):

Sustituye tu código JS por este:

```
$('#language').val(function() {
    $.post("assets/php/prove.php", {language: this.value}).done(function(data){
        alert("Success");
    }).fail(function() {
        alert("Error");
    });
});
```

Fíjate bien en el nombre de la variable `language` porque en tu código lo estás mezclando erróneamente.

Para obtener el valor en PHP sería así:

```
$language = $_POST["language"];
```

Comment: Sigue sin recoguer el valor, aunque lo haga todo lo que me has dicho, hay algo q falla en el php que no recongue el dato.